# Inline onchange submit doesn't work with webkit (Chrome or Safari)

Tags: javascript, forms, onchange

This submits on FF, but not on Chrome. Any suggestions?

```
<form action="/test" method="post" onchange="this.submit();">
   <select>
      <option value="f">f</option>
      <option value="g">g</option>
   </select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<form action="/test" method="post" >
   <select name="select" onchange="this.form.submit();">
      <option value="f">f</option>
      <option value="g">g</option>
   </select>
</form>
```

the onchange should be on the select tag. and it is a good idea to give it a name so you can retrieve the value on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

This is still a bug. The event should be triggering the listener on the form - and does when the listener is attached ala:

```
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('change', function(){alert('lol!');})
```

The issue is that the onchange attribute is broken.

The answer proposing that you move your listener should not have been accepted. There are many cases where an enclosing component may need to an onchange observer bound at render time.